# Select only the first Result /.*(?!.*==>.*).*(\n) / gm

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I'm trying to extract a syntax from a text with `/.*(?!.*==>.*).*(\n)/gm`
  but only the first line interests me.

The result that I get is all the  search matches in the document but I'm only interested in the first line.

Do you have an idea? Here is [my current regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w24pG3/1/).

In this case I want to get only `P 74 T 164 IMC 27.27`.

Comment: How about `^[^\r\n]+\n`?

Comment: Remove the m (multiline) flag

Comment: Alex : No   Remove the m (multiline) flag   don't work

Comment: Toto  ^[^\r\n]+\n    Can you tell me more ?

Comment: What is the code you are using the regex in? Testing online may turn out useless if you can't apply the regex in the target environment.

Comment: Uncheck the  `global` flag. https://regex101.com/r/w24pG3/2

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew  language Javascript in GoogleApps Script   .Tthere is a disagreement, in this case I want to get only ==> P 74 T 164 IMC 27.27 . HaR  your solution doesn't work

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53188129/edit) and add the code you're using, some sample lines and expected result. As is your question is not very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
var m;
var rx = /==>[ \t]*(.*)/;
if (m=rx.exec(s)) {
    Logger.log(m[1]);
}
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YVKYdd/1). The point is to match and consume `==>` and any number of horizontal whitespace after it, and then capture the rest of the line using a `(.*)` capturing group.

**Pattern details**

- `==>` - a literal string
- `[ \t]*` - (or `[^\S\r\n]*`) - any 0+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `(.*)` - Capturing group 1: the rest of the line.

Comment: Thanks a lot Wiktor Stribiżew ,it's not exactely what i want to obtain but it's perfect for matches ,I want to obtain results in substitution windows

Comment: @Lolowr If you can formulate that in a clear way, I will be glad to help. I mean, of you want me to help with that, let me know the input text and the expected output, and what method you want to use.

Comment: In this case I want to get only P 74 T 164 IMC 27.27. With negative lockhed The result in Substitution Windows [https://regex101.com/r/w24pG3/1/]

Comment: @Lolowr I think you ask about `.replace(/[\s\S]*?==>[ \t]*(.*)[\s\S]*/, '$1')`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/THDuyK/1).

Comment: Whaouu !!!!   @Wiktor your the Best  ++wonderful++      Attaboy!
Good things come to those who wait for